# Jpanel add method performance is very slow

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel to which i want to add a big amout of displayable Objects (90000) with the JPanel.add method, but it needs like 10 seconds, which seems too long on my PC.

```
for (Pixel p : pA) { 
    //pA is an ArrayList<Pixel> containing about 90000 of my drawable objects
    jP.add(p);  
}
```

so what does jP.add(); actually do?
or is my setup to slow?

you may check the whole sourcecode on [github](https://github.com/Haligaliman/MaturaArbeit)

Comment: Many algorithms at 100.0000 (!!!!) objects has similar or bigger problem, for example naive database fetch all the filter etc. What is main idea in Your program?

Comment: Yeah, 90,000 components is going to be slow. I'd suggest re-thinking your model. Why are you modeling a pixel with a component?

Comment: If you want to draw objects I'd suggest to have a look at Java 2D: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/

Comment: *"you may check the whole sourcecode on github"*  No thanks.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (and I mean post it here, as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32153565/edit) to the question).